# Smalltalk Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Read from StringMorph, how to write code for doing math.

`contents := InputField contents asNumber`

How could I then add a math function to this  - (1.8 + 32) to change the number  from the string?

I'm struggling to find examples online.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to read a raw string (_1.8 + 32_) by using the `contents` message. Then you need to parse it and get numbers and operations out of it, and then implement the logic behind the calculation.

Comment: I read it simpler as "how to do arithmetic in Smalltalk?"... that would simply be `result := contents - (1.8 + 32)`. To put that back to the input field, you would probably use the setter `InputField contents: result asString`.

Comment: If you just want to use the basic math operations, you can use the compiler to evaluate the InputField contents. 1.8 + 32 is a valid Smalltalk expression. That is not a very good idea, because the errors on the parsing would go to the user, that could not understand what happens. Also a large security problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer, but if you're talking about how to evaluate a valid smalltalk expression, which happens to be a math expression:

```
Smalltalk compiler evaluate: '0.0 - (1.8 + 32)'
```

printIt => -33.8